# The remote server returned error : NotFound

Tags: silverlight, wcf-data-services

Getting above error knowing that this is generic error. I tried to get exact error by writing in web.config file like this :

```
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

In WCF service I got communication-exception ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSpqG.png)) and in ViewModel I got TargetInvocationException ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uyv4f.png)). Also in ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file maxBufferSize,maxReceivedMessageSize etc increased but still it is giving this error for large amount of data. Can anybody suggest solution how to resolve this?

Edit- Service is returning data but at client side when completed event of service is called it throws error.

Comment: You need to increase "maxBufferSize", etc on the server side in the Web.config file also, did you do that?

Comment: @McGarnagle - Yes I increased "maxBufferSize" in the Web.confing file.

Comment: Facing same problem... I have too changed all the setting like maxBufferSize etc in both config files. Still no luck.